# Possible bad raid card / hard disks (LSI 9261-8i)

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, lsi, megaraid

I am in a bit of bad spot at the moment, i have a dedicated server hosted by someone else, it has a LSI 9261-8i raid card installed, attached is:

- 3x300GB SAS 15K rpm disks (in RAID5)
- 5x2TB SATA disks

now the only way i could get my system to initialize/recognise the sata disks was to configure each individual disk as RAID0, i'm assuming essentially this will treat it as JBOD?

I ask this because something has gone wrong, which the data center is trying to fix, the RAID controller is not detecting any disks after a reboot...they have tried replacing the RIAD card with an identical model, it still won't find any disks.

I have a backup of my data on the RAID5, so that's fine, but no backup of the SATA disks....if plugging these disks into a separate system directly to a standard SATA port, will it be able to read the disk as normal (providing the HDD isn't damaged in any way of course)?

Also, does anybody have any suggestions on what could be causing the RAID card not to see the disks.

I suppose i will find out soon enough, it's just that they are taking there time and i'm eager to no that my data should be safe.

Paul